# Specific type of abbreviation in textese

Tags: terminology, abbreviations, phonetics, alphabet, homophones

I would like to know if there is *preexisting metalanguage* or a *term* to describe the following types of abbreviations often present in textese or SMS language:

1. see → **c**,
2. you → **u**,
3. are → **r**,
4. your → **ur**, etc.

The abbreviation involves a **letter of the alphabet** representing a word that is one of its **homophones**, e.g., 'see' /siː/ → 'c'/siː/, etc.

The term that I’m looking for would be analogous to “initialism” for
“for your information” → FYI.

I have already done a fair amount of research and cannot find an answer; e.g., I looked at the Leet Wikipedia page prior to posting this question and the information there does not provide a clear enough answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet

Comment: I actually came across [Origin and use of the abbreviation 'u' for ‘you’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462969/origin-and-use-of-the-abbreviation-u-for-you) recently. I'm not sure if it sufficiently addresses your own question—but it might help you add more clarification if it doesn't. (The question has less detail, but it is very specific in what it asks.)

Comment: That is an interesting question on this website but what I am REALLY looking for is some sort of metalanguage to define this specific type of abbreviation e.g. FYI - "for your information" is an **initialism**.

Comment: Doesn’t that lead onto swampy ground like FYI and MAD, USA and NASA all being initialisms but not all acronyms?

Does anything stop solo “U” or any single character being an acronym?

How would you handle the different forms “UR” and, eg, “ID”?

Comment: An acronym, by definition, is a word or name formed as an abbreviation from the _initial components_ in a phrase or a word. I don't think there would be any "swampy ground". If 'you' were to be abbreviated using this description, it would be **y** not **u**.